# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Mrc' in python using jupyter notebook

Tags: python

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? Here's my code and the error I am getting. 
p.s I have given the somefile.mrc path correctly.

```
import numpy
import Mrc
a = Mrc.bindFile('home/smitha/deep-image-prior/data/Falcon_2015_05_14-20_42_18.mrc')
# a is a NumPy array with the image data memory mapped from
# somefile.mrc.  You can use it directly with any function
# that will take a NumPy array.
hist = numpy.histogram(a, bins=200)
# a.Mrc is an instances of the Mrc class.  One thing
# you can do with that class is print out key information from the header.
a.Mrc.info()
wavelength0_nm = a.Mrc.hdr.wave[0]
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         3 a = Mrc.bindFile('/home/smitha/deep-image-prior/data/Falcon_2015_05_14-20_42_18.mrc')
>         4 hist = numpy.histogram(a, bins=200)
>   ----> 5 a.Mrc.info()
>         6 wavelength0_nm = a.Mrc.hdr.wave[0]
>         7
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Mrc'

​

Comment: This is similar to (at least a comment in) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959716/what-does-bindfile-do. How did you make the mrc file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Mrc'` means that you are trying to access an object's `'Mrc'` member even though the object is `NoneType`, thus the object has no such member.

You are trying to do so in `a.Mrc.info()`, meaning that `a` is `None` (the unique instance of `NoneType`). The reason is that either

```
a = Mrc.bindFile('/home/smitha/deep-image-prior/data/Falcon_2015_05_14-20_42_18.mrc')
```

OR

```
hist = numpy.histogram(a, bins=200)
```

had assigned `None` to `a`. Check `type(a)` after each line, see where the problem is, and debug the function

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers thanks for the distinction! but wouldn't it be OK to say, for example, that `a=1` is assigning an `int` into `a`, and the same goes for `a=None`?

Comment: A python function cannot rebind a name in the calling scope (unless the function is a closure defined in the calling scope - which is obviously not the case here - or it does some very evil things with the call stack, which is certainly not the case here either), so the chances the `hist = numpy.histogram(a, bins=200)` statement would rebind `a` are close to zero.

Comment: @CIsForCookies python classes are objects, so saying that "`a is NoneType`" means that, _literally_, `a` is bound to the `NoneType` class object - not to the `None` object. When you say that (after `a = 1`) "`a` is AN `int`", it means that `a` is an instance of `int`, which is not the same as saying that `a is int` ;-)